# Access token in web api client IdSrv3 authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm using IdSrv3 for authentication. I need to get access_token inside my web api owin client to pass bearer authentication in another web api client.
My Startup.cs code:

```
public class Startup
{
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            var identityServerPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerPath"];

            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = $"{identityServerPath}/core",

                RequiredScopes = new[] { "openid"},
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,

                // client credentials for the introspection endpoint
                ClientId = "someid"
            });
        }
}
```

I'm trying to get access token by this way:

```
var claims = (User as ClaimsPrincipal).Claims;
var AccessToken = claims.First(x => x.Type == "access_token").Value;
```

How to get access_token? claims variable is empty.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? :)

Comment: @JohnKorsnes fixed :)

Comment: Cool :) Please provide an answer for the next dev, if it can benefit others :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the "PreserveAccessToken" property to true (it defaults to false). For example:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://localhost:44331",
    ClientId = "apiOne",    
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    RequiredScopes = new[] {"apiOne"},
    ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
    PreserveAccessToken = true
});
```

This will preserve the access token as a claim. You can then retrieve it as you are doing above. Except, the claim is "token", not "access_token".

Comment: It's empty again :(

Comment: @AstemirAlmov - So, there are no claims present at all? Perhaps you can post the code that shows the configuration of the other pieces in play? For example, the client calling this web API and the IdentityServer configuration of that client?